# How to retrieve Firebase pushed key?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an event I'm storing in my database. It is stored as

```
events
   my_party123
     info
       -KZbdiR_PBrAwxYvUR4U
         name: 'John'
         city: 'Los Angeles'
   my_party124
      ...
```

However, I'm trying to retrieve this info and I can't quite get it.

I tried

```
ref
  .child('events')
  .child('my_party123') // I also tried .push('my_party123')
  .once('value')
  .then(snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot.key) // my_party123
    console.log(snapshot.val().info) 
    // this shows object with
    // "-KZbdiR_PBrAwxYvUR4U" property, this is the pushed key property  
    im trying to access
   })
```

`.pushed` is creating new keys when i called it - how do i just access the value stored in my database?

Comment: I can use `Object.keys(snapshot.val().info)[0]` to get the details, but this feels very much like a hack

Comment: If you're storing the values with unique keys, your comment seems like it'd be the way to go. If you have the ability to reorganize your data structure, can you make `info` a child of `my_party123` instead of giving it a unique identifier? Then you could `firebase.database.ref( 'events/my_party123/info')` and be good to go

Comment: @imjared that was a typo on my end. i accidentally switched up the structure. it's stored the way you specified

Comment: do you recommend a better way of storing new events then? i did this in the future case that the event names can be changed as users can register to these events, since each of these event names "my_party123" etc map to the route. domain.com/my_party123. i use a separate field in my db under `event_id/<pushedkeyid/event_id(which points to my_party123)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking to have unique event URLs that point at events, I'd recommend a change to your data structure to be something more like:

```
events
  -KZ123PUSHID
    name: 'John'
    location: 'Los Angeles'
  -KZ124PUSHID
    name: 'Morgan'
    location: 'New York City'
eventNames
  my_party_123: '-KZ123PUSHID'
  sweet_nyc_part: '-KZ124PUSHID'
```

Then, in your code, you could do something like:

```
var eventNamesRef = firebase.database().ref('eventNames');
var eventsRef = firebase.database().ref('events');

var event;    
eventNamesRef.child(nameFromUrl).once('value').then(nameSnap => {
  eventsRef.child(nameSnap.val()).on('value', eventSnap => {
    event = eventSnap.val();
  });
});
```

Comment: wow, this is perfect. much better than hacking it together like i felt i was doing. thanks Michael!